# How to solve 'Could not find a part of the path..' issue on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, zxing, memorystream

I'm using Zxing library to create a barcode and memory stream to save it to the server folder.
Everything works fine on local as well as a testing server, but when I publish code on client-server it won't create a barcode image nor get location of image on that server location.
Here is the code I created for this process-

```
            var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
            writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;// QR_CODE;
            var result = writer.Write(printArray[0]);
            string path = Server.MapPath("/images/code/" + ComplaintId + ".jpg");    
            var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {    
                    barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
```

This code is used to save bar code on the server location.

```
 string ImagePath = ComplaintId + ".jpg";
 imgQRcode.Src = "~/images/code/" + ImagePath;
```

and used this line to bind it to img tag.

it shows error like

> Could not find a part of the path g:\xyz\images\code\103.jpg

this only happen on client-server not elsewhere.

- **---------Edit 1--------**

As I was still facing issues while creating image on a host server, I made a few changes in code now. Instead of saving barcode image I'm converting it to Base64 string and using it.

Here is code changes

```
            var barWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
            barWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;// QR_CODE;
            var barResult = barWriter.Write("printbar");                
            var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(barResult);
            string bs64 = ToBase64String(barcodeBitmap, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

and Tobase64String function

```
public static string ToBase64String(Bitmap bmp, ImageFormat imageFormat)
    {
        string base64String = string.Empty;        
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(memoryStream, imageFormat);        
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] byteBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer = null;
        return base64String;
    }
```

and function to bind base64 to image

```
 public static string GetImageSrc(string base64Src)
    {
        return "data:image/png;base64," + base64Src;
    }
```

to feed it to iTextcharp use

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bs64);
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
```

Comment: Are you sure that "images" and "code" folder is exists ?

Comment: ... and G:\ and G:\xyz?

Comment: Have you tried to build your paths using `Path.Combine` ?

Comment: Unrelated: Do you get good results saving a qr to jpg?

Comment: g:\xyz\.. is a server path of client

Comment: yes images\code\ directory exist on server.

Comment: about `Path.cobine` i never needed it a same code is working on 2 other server

Comment: I think it needs `Server.MapPath(...)`.

Comment: I adjusted things now, instead of saving and then use now I'm creating base64 string and using it bind while showing barcode.